# How to post List of data in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I want to post my `json` data from `Xamarin.Forms` application to my `asp.net web api`.

My Models Class

```
public class MyModel2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ShopName { get; set; }
    public List<Order2> ListOrder { get; set; }
}

public class Order2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller code is below :

```
public class MyModel2Controller : ApiController
{
    private MPTContext db = new MPTContext();

    // GET: api/MyModel2
    public IQueryable<MyModel2> GetMyModel2()
    {
        return db.MyModel2;
    }

    // GET: api/MyModel2/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(MyModel2))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMyModel2(int id)
    {
        MyModel2 myModel2 = await db.MyModel2.FindAsync(id);
        if (myModel2 == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(myModel2);
    }

    // PUT: api/MyModel2/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutMyModel2(int id, MyModel2 myModel2)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != myModel2.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(myModel2).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!MyModel2Exists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/MyModel2
    [ResponseType(typeof(MyModel2))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMyModel2(MyModel2 myModel2)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.MyModel2.Add(myModel2);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = myModel2.Id }, myModel2);
    }

    // DELETE: api/MyModel2/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(MyModel2))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteMyModel2(int id)
    {
        MyModel2 myModel2 = await db.MyModel2.FindAsync(id);
        if (myModel2 == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.MyModel2.Remove(myModel2);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(myModel2);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool MyModel2Exists(int id)
    {
        return db.MyModel2.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

My RestService Code is below:

MyModel2 model1:

```
public async Task<MyModel2> SaveOrder()
{
    model1 = new MyModel2
    {
        ShopName = "MMSHop",
        ListOrder = new List<Order2>()
        {
            new Order2
            {
                ProductName = "MMPRoduct"
            }
        }
    };
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model1);
    var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var result = await client.PostAsync(MainUrl, content);
    return model1;
}
```

My Button Event Handler is

```
MyModel2 OOmodel;
private async void OnOrderPlace(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OOmodel = await OOrest.SaveOrder();
}
```

When I press the button I get json data like

Json Result Image:
[image: screenshot 1]

but on my `asp.net web api` result seems like that

`Asp.net Web API` result:
[image: screenshot 2]
as you see `ListOrder` is null however in my application I am also sending its data.
I also try to use postman from that i get 201 code (successful or generated) also in my Server Explorer --> Order2 Table i get poster values in Orders2 Table but not on server.

Comment: Show us your Web API controller

Comment: please check my controller i have edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force Web API to read a simple type from the request body, add the [`FromBody`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) attribute to the parameter

```
// POST: api/MyModel2
[ResponseType(typeof(MyModel2))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMyModel2([FromBody] MyModel2 myModel2)
```

then in `GetMyModel2` method

```
// GET: api/MyModel2
public IQueryable<MyModel2> GetMyModel2()
{
  return db.MyModel2.Include(x => x.ListOrder);
}
```

Comment: `MyModel2` is the same for Web API and Xamarin.Forms? Did you try to debug it? What value of `result` after post? If you need help then add additional details, because I can't guess why "Its not working".  See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I try to keep model name same and different but still facing problem. Result after post is shown in the image. I also try to use postman from that i get 201 code (successful or generated) also in my Server Explorer --> Order2 Table i get poster values in Orders2 Table but not on server.

Comment: Yes, I try that and its giving the same properties as api. As i mention in my post data is also storing in ab other table name as "Order2" but its not showing in "ListOrder". I want to display data of "Order2" in "ListOrder"

Comment: ok, thanks. try this: `return db.MyModel2.Incude(x => x.ListOrder)` in method `GetMyModel2`. let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks its now showing "ListOrder" data. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to have been of help